# Are Makita Makpac containers compatible with Tanos T-Loc systainers (Festool)?

Tags: tools

Are Makita Makpac containers compatible with Tanos systainers (Festool)?

Tanos systainers seem to be rather expensive while Makita Makpac prices are good. But still would be nice to know so all my tools can be stacked together - in case I decide to buy some Festool instrument which may come with Festool systainer right away?

[Are systainer tool cases of different companies compatible with each other?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1503) question does not answer this specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are systainer tool cases of different companies compatible with each other?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/are-systainer-tool-cases-of-different-companies-compatible-with-each-other)

Comment: An answer on the previous question has been edited to specifically answer this.  Really it was pretty clear, many companies distribute systainers.  They're all compatible with each other (with the restriction that 1st generation won't stack on top of 2nd generation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks and what I read, they are the same as the old style Tanos Systainers.  Assuming that is so, they will stack underneath the newer T-LOC systainers, but not on top of them.